# Does my apache cache my images?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a folder for customer avatar upload and I set up an apache server pointing to this folder to get customer avatar images.
It seem to be a very strange symptom my system get right now as following:

1. I update an avatar image in the folder
2. I access to the image by browser, but I see it displays the old one on browser though I refresh (Ctrl+F5) many times.
3. After a time duration (nearly 1 min), I refresh the above url, and I got the lastest image dislayed.

Is this symptom relating to my Apache configuration? Could anyone help me to figure out which setting affects? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am guessing that you have not enabled any of the apache caching modules. If this is the case then this behavior is due to browser's caching on the client side. You can verify this by opening the url in a browser's private session after updating the image. You can also verify by looking into apache's **access.log** file and check if you can see any request entry for accessing the image or not. If it's not then it is being directly served from browser's cache.